# How to provide additional parameter to implicit conversion

Tags: java, scala

I'm working on this exercise from "Scala for impatient" book, from chapter "Implicits":

> Compare objects of the class `java.awt.Point` according to their distance to the origin.

I haven't come up with anything better then this:

```
class PointDistOrdered( origin: Point, p1: Point) extends Ordered[Point] {
  private def compareDoubles(d1: Double, d2: Double) = 
    if (d1 < d2) -1 
    else 
      if (d1 == d2) 0 
      else 1
  def compare(p2: Point) = compareDoubles(p1.distance(origin), p2.distance(origin))
}
object PointConversions {
  def getDistOrder(origin: Point) = (p: Point) => new PointDistOrdered(origin, p)
}
```

And this is how I use it, which looks ugly to me:

```
import PointOrders.getDistOrder
implicit def order = getDistOrder(new Point(0, 0))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create a separate class composed of `Point`, just to provide `Ordering` implicit (typeclass).

```scala
implicit val PointOrdering: Ordering[Point] = new Ordering[Point] {
  def compare(a: Point, b: Point): Int = ??? // your impl
}
```

Then points can be compared/sorted using this, for example using `Sorting` companion object.